# Cannot connect to remote server in RSelenium (rsDriver) - hangs and is followed by an error

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

This is the usage of rsDriver I have:

```
library(RSelenium)

driver <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome", chromever = "74.0.3729.6", geckover = NULL, iedrver = NULL, phantomver = NULL)
```

I realize docker is the recommended way to get things going, but I'm writing a script for people whom would have major difficulty in getting it started every time (also rsDriver works at home but not at work...).

When I run the above block, this is the output:

```
checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking chromedriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Could not open chrome browser.
Client error message:
subscript out of bounds
Check server log for further details.
```

This is after it hangs for a solid few minutes.  A chrome browser is opened up after a few seconds though, with "data;" in the search bar, but it'll close after the few minutes.

Trying to run `driver$client$open()` I get

```
Error in resContent[["status"]] : subscript out of bounds
```

This hangs for about the same amount of time.

After I get this, I run

```
> criver <- driver$client
> criver$navigate("http://www.reddit.com/r/nba")
```

Which also hangs for roughly the same amount of time, and gives me back this error:

```
  Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
```

Note i'm working on a mobile hotspot in order to bypass corporate firewalls and whatnot.  I ran getStatus() and got the following:

```
> criver$getStatus()
$ready
[1] TRUE

$message
[1] "Server is running"

$build
$build$revision
[1] "d1d3728cae"

$build$time
[1] "2019-04-24T16:15:24"

$build$version
[1] "4.0.0-alpha-1"


$os
$os$arch
[1] "amd64"

$os$name
[1] "Windows 10"

$os$version
[1] "10.0"


$java
$java$version
[1] "1.8.0_201"
```

I'm not sure what the issue is at all.  I added in the path to chromedriver.exe as a PATH environment variable and restarted R.  Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Could you solve the problem? I am having the exact same issue.

Comment: @Nivel Apart from the obvious solution being "get around your workplace firewall" you _also_ need Chrome Developer Tools allowed.  After getting both of those, the automation worked as I expected it to.